# Keyboard in front of my interface

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've many Entries and Labels in my Interface, what can I do to my page scrolldown if my keyboard is in front of any element? I tried to implement a scrollview in my xaml but no results...

[image: Example of my UI][image: Keyboard problem]

Comment: Add xaml code which you have tried so its more useful to help you

Comment: here :) https://pastebin.com/cvuQbcL6

Comment: @IgorHenriques please don't use pastebin for code. Just include it in your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
Best way to resolve this was to wrap the login part into a scrollview (similar to what you are doing already) and using custom renderers:

**Android:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ModernLogin), typeof(ModernLoginPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderer
{
    public class ModernLoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public ModernLoginPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);


            // Deactivate SoftInput View Adjustment for this window
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                (this.Context as FormsApplicationActivity).Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);             
            }
        }

        protected override void OnWindowVisibilityChanged([GeneratedEnum] ViewStates visibility)
        {
            // Enable SoftInput View Adjustment after moving away from this window
            if (visibility == ViewStates.Gone)
            {
                (this.Context as FormsApplicationActivity).Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);
            }
            base.OnWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    }
}
```

**iOS:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ModernLogin), typeof(ModernLoginPageRenderer))]

namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderer
{
    public class ModernLoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        NSObject observerHideKeyboard;
        NSObject observerShowKeyboard;

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var cp = Element as ModernLogin;
            if (cp != null)
            {
                foreach (var g in View.GestureRecognizers)
                {
                    g.CancelsTouchesInView = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            observerHideKeyboard = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification, OnKeyboardNotification);
            observerShowKeyboard = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification, OnKeyboardNotification);
        }

        public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(observerHideKeyboard);
            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(observerShowKeyboard);
        }

        void OnKeyboardNotification(NSNotification notification)
        {
            if (!IsViewLoaded) return;

            var frameBegin = UIKeyboard.FrameBeginFromNotification(notification);
            var frameEnd = UIKeyboard.FrameEndFromNotification(notification);

            var page = Element as ModernLogin;
            if (page != null)
            {
                var padding = page.Padding;
                page.Padding = new Thickness(padding.Left, padding.Top, padding.Right, padding.Bottom + frameBegin.Top - frameEnd.Top);
            }
        }
    }
```